# How do you return col2 where col3 share/overlap col2?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

My goal is to have a Rails Active Record Query or SQL Query that takes two variable `USER_ID`s and returns all, as unique, of the `ORG_ID`s where those `USER_ID`s share/overlap a `ORG_ID`. By as unique, I mean instead of returning `[8,8]` for below, it would just return `8`.

```
+-------------------------+
| ID   | ORG_ID | USER_ID |
+-------------------------+
|  "51" |   "8"  |  "51"  |
|  "52" |   "8"  |  "52"  |
+-------------------------+
```

I would like to figure out how to query my `TABLE` with `51` and `52` as variables for `USER_ID` that return `8` from `ORG_ID`. In the above example, I would like to return 8.

```
+------------------------+
|  ID | ORG_ID | USER_ID |
+------------------------+
| "1" |   "5"  |  "1"    |
| "2" |   "2"  |  "2"    |
| "3" |   "3"  |  "3"    |
| "4" |   "2"  |  "4"    |
| "5" |   "3"  |  "9"    |
| "6" |   "1"  |  "10"   |
| "7" |   "2"  |  "9"    |
| "8" |   "2"  |  "10"   |
| "9" |   "3"  |  "9"    |
| "10"|   "3"  |  "10"   |
+------------------------+
```

In the next above example, I would like to use `9` and `10` as variables for `USER_ID` which would match/overlap for `ORG_ID`s `2` and `3` to return [2,3] in the Ruby Method.

I would like to learn how to do this with active record queries with Rails or SQL. I currently use PostGreSQL 10 for my Database and all values above are bigints. I'm using Rails 5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get the point you should pluck columns where user_id is 9 or 10, then manipulate the array. Or maybe thare is a straight query. Anyway this is one possibility.

```
Model.where(....).pluck(:id, :org_id, :user_id)
```

Let's say this is the pluck result:

```
pluck_query_result.map!{ |e| e[1..2] }.group_by{ |e| e[0] }.reject{ |_, v| v.size < 2 }.keys
```

You can do:

```
pluck_query_result.map! { |e| e[1..2] }.group_by {|e| e[0]}.reject{ |_, v| v.size < 2}.keys
# => [3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a self join on the distinct ORG_ID in your table should trim this down, like so:

```
select distinct org9.org_id
from (select distinct org_id from org where user_id = 9) as org9
inner join (select distinct org_id from org where user_id = 10) as org10
    on org9.org_id = org10.org_id
```